# WIX: Executable does not find dlls in subdirs

Tags: c#, wix

i´m trying to create a msi using Wix and have the installation folder use a given structure, in this case put third party dll´s in a subfolder called lib.

The problem is, that MyApplication.exe crashes. Debuging told me that it can not locate the Interactions.dll. If I put the dll in the INSTALLFOLDER and not in the subfolder it works fine.

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApplication" Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Executable"/>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
</Feature>

<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="Organisation" Name="OrganizationFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApplication">
          <Directory Id="lib" Name="lib"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="Executable" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="MyApplication.exe" Guid="*">
      <File Id="MyApplication.exe" Name="MyApplication.exe" Source="$(var.MyApplication_TargetDir)MyApplication.exe" Vital="yes" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="lib">
    <Component Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" Guid="*">
          <File Id="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" Name="Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" Source="$(var.MyApplication_TargetDir)Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with wix, but instead is how the .Net runtime locates assemblies - it does not know you want it to search the lib sub-directory for the Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll. You could use a probing element in the application's config file to tell it where to find this and other dependant assemblies (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies) for details):

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="lib"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Also note, by convention, dependant assemblies are usually in a "bin" sub-directory, and not "lib"; at least that is the convention used by ASP .Net, so you might consider using that convention yourself.